# Selectbox hide first option entry on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to hide the first option i.e. `<option>Select One</option>` when the user clicks the dropdown box to see the options. So the text **Select One** does not appear in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is no reliable cross browser way to hide `option` elements, your best bet is to remove it on `focus` and add it again on `blur`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var first = jQuery('#myselect').find('option').first();
    jQuery('#myselect').on('focus', function (e) {
        first.remove();
    }).on('blur', function (e) {
        jQuery(this).find('option').first().before(first);
    });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/q7rq1z75/2/)

Comment: +1, was just typing up the same answer in plain ol' JS. `display:none` works in some browsers, just not all of them unfortunately.  There's no point in adding the element back on blur, however, and it causes problems in the fiddle you added.

Comment: Hmm, you're right it does cause problems. I was thinking that the OP would want it to add it back if nothing was selected but I didn't really think it through, since once the first is removed, another has to be selected!

Comment: problem in example two if I select it removes First but if i go back and try to change my selection it removes Second.

Answer (score 7):

You can use your plain HTML for hiding the first Element of option when select is opened as:

```
<select name="list">
    <option selected="selected" hidden>First Element</option>
    <option>Second Element</option>
    <option>Third Element</option>

</select>
```

Here is the working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sujan_mhrzn/y5kxtkc6/

Comment: This is the best and most simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

As a quick CSS option you could give the dropdown an id and then

```
#cat option:first-child {
 display: none;
 }
```

The above uses #cat as the id for the dropdown

[Tutorial for this solution](http://harrisonproject.co.uk/my-blog/disable-first-option-from-drop-down-css/)

Comment: This is what I do. Wondering why these guys are looking for Javascript solutions when as simple as this will do the job.

Comment: Best solution indeed ! No need to use another JS. Lightest solution IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The only cross-browser method is to remove it entirely.  In plain ol' JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
sel.onfocus = function () {
    select.onfocus = null;
    sel.removeChild(sel.firstChild);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#mySelect").focus(function () { 
    $(this).remove(this.firstChild).unbind(arguments.callee); 
});
```

Comment: the problem is every time I select and click away and then reselect again it removes the next one.

Comment: @acctman: of course it does - how silly of me. Updated, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the option, the simples code would be:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

mySelect.onfocus = function() { mySelect.removeChild(mySelect.options[0]); }
```

where `mySelect` is the id of the select box.

Edit: I changed the code to append an event listener for the focus event. This code, however, will remove the first option **every** time you select the select box. Pretty sure this is not what you need. You could use onblur to append the option again, but I don't know if that's what you need. Please clarify what you want to do.

Comment: close to what i'm looking for is there a way to do something like Onfocus hide elementById('hideMe') <option id=hideMe>Select Type</option>